# Capture Named Group in Shell Script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting

I have a requirement to capture the named groups in the shell script similar to how we have the provision in the python as below:

```
(?P<year>.*)~(?P<name>.*)
1983~Harman
```

It does capture year as 1983 and name as Harman.
I read about capturing the group but not the named group using sed and awk command , but I am looking for named group capturing in shell script , any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Regex libraries in Perl, Ruby, Python, etc. support named capturing groups.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, dont we have any such provision in the shell script? or would you mind suggesting any alternative to capturing named groups in shell scripts.

Comment: POSIX regex flavors do not support named capturing groups.

Comment: Capture unnamed groups? I don't see how named groups are anything more than a convenience. `[[ "1983~Harman" =~ (.*)~(.*) ]]`; 1983 and Harmon will be indices 1 and 2, respectively, of the `BASH_REMATCH` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a perl one-liner in your shell script:

```
$ echo "1983~Harman" | perl -pe '/(?<year>.*)~(?<name>.*)/; $_ = "Name: $+{name}, Year: $+{year}\n"'
Name: Harman, Year: 1983
```

Note, perl 5.10 is required for named capture groups

Comment: @Harmandeep Singh Kalsi: Does this fit your needs? Any questions?

Comment: The string could be anything , this is just the sample I took . Can we do it in some generic way?

Comment: It's up to you what you pipe into perl, what regex you apply in perl, and how you format the output in perl. Anything particular in mind?